# Dual of a linear program.

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have a linear program of a set covering problem;
\begin{align}
& &\underset{}{\text{min}} 
 &\sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i & & & \\
& \text{s.t.} & &  \sum_{i=1}^n b_{i,j}x_i \geq d_j & \forall j=1,\dots,m\\
& & &  x_i \geq 0 & \forall i=1,\dots,n
\end{align}
and I want to write the dual of this primal by rewriting it to the dual of a linear program in standard form and then taking the dual, because the dual of the dual is the primal linear program (right?). I finally achieve,
\begin{align}
& &\underset{}{\text{max}} 
 &\sum_{j=1}^m d_jy_j & & & \\
& \text{s.t.} & &  \sum_{j=1}^m b_{i,j}y_j \leq c_i & \forall i =1,\dots,m\\
& & &  y_j \geq 0 & \forall j=1,\dots,m
\end{align}
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine, just a minor typo.\begin{align}
& &\underset{}{\text{max}} 
 &\sum_{j=1}^m d_jy_j & & & \\
& \text{s.t.} & &  \sum_{j=1}^m b_{i,j}y_j \leq c_i & \forall i =1,\dots,\color{blue}n\\
& & &  y_j \geq 0 & \forall j=1,\dots,m
\end{align}